# ASP.net How can I invalidate in textchanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

How can I invalidate the page in textchanged event.

I have a simple form with textboxes and a button to submit 
I would like to disable the button or stop the submission if the text entered is not valid. 
the validity is to be checked in the textchanged event since I have some db operation to check the validity of the content. 
If I can somehow invalidate the page in the textchanged event then it might be easier 
pls give me some easy way to implement this 
thanks
Shomaail

Comment: Why? The TextChanged event is only fired in a PostBack to the server (e.g. when the user presses a button). The whole point of validators is that you don't PostBack to the server until the fields are valid (assuming ClientSide validation is enabled). I assume you're using validator controls.

Comment: I agree to u. But I need a solution to my problem. with postback or without. the txtbox content has to be checked with DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my own problem perfectly. I used the customvalidator OnServerValidate Event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.onservervalidate(v=vs.110).aspx

Now in my TextChanged event I show up a warning if the data entered is not correct and in the button_click event of my submit button I call Page.Validate() that subsequently calls OnServerValidate event handler of each custom validator associated with a text box.

```
 protected void btnIssueItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate();
        if (!Page.IsValid)
            return;
....
}


protected void tbRoomID_CustomValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        BAL bal = new BAL();
        args.IsValid = bal.GetRoomByRoomID(Int32.Parse(args.Value)).Count == 0 ? false : true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Button Enabled Property to true of false, ie:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtData" OnTextChanged="txtData_TextChanged"
                                            AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" OnClik="btnSave_Click"></asp:Button>
```

On Code Behid:

```
      protected void txtData_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if(txtData.Text == "something")
           {
               btnSave.Enabled = True;
           }
           else
               btnSave.Enabled = False;
        }
```

Comment: This will fail if there are two or more txt boxes. Any of the txtbox will make the button enable and the user will get a chance to receive error.

Comment: how do you validate the data? regex or some kinda string comparison?

Comment: once we are in the txtData_TextChanged we can check thru string comparison or regex or any other way. The problem in focus is that I need to have a way in which if the data in any of the txtbox is not correct the page submission becomes impossible. I need to check the content of the txtbox with some DB operation